# How do I add custom actions to UWP installer like we do for normal desktop application installers?

Tags: uwp, windows-installer, custom-action, appx

I want UWP installer to detect the installed .net version, handle uninstalling of an older build  before installing the new one, allow system administers to do a mass install to PCs within their network. All the three things were easy to do for normal desktop application as we could create custom actions and do silent installations. But how do I achieve these with the appx file?

Comment: Are you talking about native UWP app or Win32 app converted using Desktop Bridge?

Comment: @MarianDolinský Native UWP

Comment: So just stick with what Herdo said.

Comment: @MarianDolinský Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply cannot. The installation process of [`uwp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) apps is standartized to work on all devices supported by the OS. Custom install actions do not make sense when writing the app for e.g. Hololense, PC, mobile and XBOX. You'll get nowhere.

> detect the installed .net version

Why would you worry about this? You ship your application compiled for a certain CLR version. If a PC is missing this version, the administrators are at fault.

> uninstalling of an older build before installing the new one

This will happen automatically when installing a newer version.

> allow system administers to do a mass install to PCs within their network

This is possible, but not an integrated part of the installation process. Your administrators have to apply a certain deployment process in order to role out the app to all computers.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially going to have to understand the ins-and-outs of sideloading your UWP LOB App. Once that is understood, you can simply write an installer the way you used to, and the installer would call all of the appropriate powershell commands for most of the workflows, and setup scheduled tasks for when the user logs in to accomplish the other workflows. (I recommend wix for your msi, msiexec to run that msi, psexec to run some of the msiexec commands headlessly under the system account, and a vm of win10 to test your msi)

First off, you'll need to ensure your LOB App is packaged with a "signing certificate" issued to your organization by a certificate authority. That will tell windows that your application is "signed off" to be actually built by the company that it says it is.

Second, you need to make sure the target machines are in sideload mode.

> Configure PCs for Sideloading Requirements:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sideload-apps-with-dism-s14#span-idsideloadingrequirementsspanspan-idsideloadingrequirementsspanspan-idsideloadingrequirementsspanconfigure-pcs-for-sideloading-requirements

Since you want to "allow system administers to do a mass install to PCs within their network" they're going to want to be able to do the installs headlessly, and for all users. So, you need to include provisioning the application into the installer.

## Provisioning LOB Apps

Its important to understand that you can provision the application to the "online" windows 10 image of the target machine(s), or the "offline" windows 10 image as it is prepared for creation. Online edits to the image are what the admins will want, since the machines they deploy to will be already running in this scenario.

Provisioning will provide the UWP LOB App to a windows user as they log on, if the application isn't already there in the first place. This falls short when updates need to happen though -- leaving updating the app up to another party. It is simply a way to provide a single version of a LOB App to a user, one time. It also has restrictions, one being that when the provisioning is done there cannot be any users actively logged onto the machine, so it must be done headless with tools like SCCM or PSExec and must be using the SYSTEM account. Another restriction is that the image can only have a total of 24 provisioned apps.

### Adding a provisioned LOB App

Provisioning can be done via powershell cmdlet (Must be 64bit version of powershell being called if its a 64 bit system)

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath <yourpackagepath> -DependencyPackagePath <yourdependencypackagepath> -SkipLicense
```

^ Be logged out from all users - so run this via psexec as SYSTEM or from SCCM

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sideload-apps-with-dism-s14

### Updating a provisioned LOB App

The newer version of the provisioned LOB App
***can only be applied*** by the following cmdlet (via powershell) ***for each user*** that has signed into the PC running the Windows image.

```
> Add-AppxPackage
```

^ be logged in as the target user when running that

### Removing a provisioned LOB App

Remove the provisioned LOB App from the image:

```
> Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName MyAppxPkg
```

^ Be logged out from all users - so run this via psexec as SYSTEM or from SCCM

Uninstall occurrences of the old version the application from each user that has been active:

```
> Remove-AppxPackage MyAppxPkg
```

^ be logged in as the target user when running that

**tl;dr** - *Lots of challenges to overcome for a typical installer of a UWP LOB App, but it can be done if you want!*